# Regex character required between 1st and 8th character

Tags: regex

I am currently using this regex to limit the characters that can be used "([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)". I now have an additional requirement to require a hyphen between the 1st and 8th character. I am not sure where to begin for this and my search results have not been fruitful. Could anyone point me in a direction or give me pointers of where to get started with this request? I can usually cobble together some regex on my own through examples here and elsewhere on the web, but I can't find anything similar to these requirements.

here are some good examples of what I mean:

- this-isvalid
- so-isthis

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, typically when you know the requirements use an online regex checker.

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

There's a number of them, you can google them.

You can go ahead and specify between 1 and 7 copies of that and then a dash so something like:

```
(^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,7}-[A-Za-z0-9_]+)
```

Comment: http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRifpr0sDA/index.html

Click Java, it'll show you the share code and that it works for the given examples.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I ended up using "([A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,8}-[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)" and used the site you linked to validate it. I see that the curly braces give a range to repeat the first element after trying to research what it was doing.

Comment: This solution is wrong. It gives `true` for the input `12345678-1`, while the requirement was to have the hyphen between the 1st and the 8th char.

Comment: Yeah, Dekel's right. Corrected. Should be 1-7 copies I specified 1-8.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not good. `1-8` returns true (unless there isn't a minimum chars requirement, and if so the answer is correct).

Comment: Right again. Needs to force the start of the string to demand it match from the start to the dash properly.

Comment: http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRifpr0sDA/index.html